# How to restore svn information(url) of maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn

I have accidentally deleted `.svn` directory from my maven project. Now when I started eclipse the projected shows no connections to svn repository. I am not able to assign the svn url to the project.

How can I assign the repository url to the maven project in eclipse to be able to synchronize.

Answer (score 0):

First: make a backup. (zip the current folder)

Then: within eclipse you should be able to simply share the project (again) and select the SVN repository. Eclipse usually syncs the sources and the repository. Usually nothing gets lost in the process but better be safe and make a backup.

For maven no action should be required. There is the scm section in the pom.xml but that probably did not change. As long as no plugin reads the SVN revision number or you do a release locally maven will be fine.